# @model decorator from vue-property-decorator generates vue-warn: Avoid mutating

Tags: typescript, annotations, vuejs2

I use typescript with [this](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) lib. And I have following code in file `HomePage.vue` :

```
<template>
    <div>Write something x: <input v-model="someName" type="text"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Model, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class HomePage extends Vue {
    @Model() someName: string;
}
</script>
```

After compilation, run in browser and type something on input box i get in chrome console following vue warrning:

*[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "someName"*

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For v-model you should use properties defined inside `data`.

I see that you're using a shorthand `@Model` but what you need is `@Provide` to define `data` properties.

`@Provide() foo = 'foo'`

See https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator

Comment: Thank you :) - before I not read "compilation output" but behaviour is specified there (however name "@Model" is a little miss leading in my opinion)

Answer (score 7):

TL:DR

I'm new in Vue (coming from React) but from what I understand the answer above is not wrong but it doesn't answer the question of how to use @Model decorator. Provide and Inject is an overkill for passing props from parent to child. The documentation is not clear, so I scratched my head a lot on this one. But remember that the package is referring to `props`. Hence `@Prop`, @`PropSync` and `@Model` should be at the child component. Here is what I did and it didn't throw out that horrible console error. Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <input type="text" v-model="modelText" />
    <Child 
      :modelText="modelText"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Child from './Child.vue';

@Component({
  components: {
    Child,
  }
})
export default class Parent extends Vue {
  private modelText: string = 'model-text';
}
</script>
```

And for the child component:

```
<template>
    <div>
      @Model: {{modelText}}
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import { Prop, PropSync, Model } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({

})
export default class Child extends Vue {
  @Model('input', { type: String }) modelText!: string;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Since v. 9.1.2 `view-property-decorator` now supports the `@VModel` decorator.

Where

```
import { Vue, Component, VModel } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class CustomComponent extends Vue {
  @VModel() name!: string
}
```

will make it possible to use two-way-databinding with `name` inside the component and `v-model="..."` from the outside. Without the annoying warnings!

https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#-vmodelpropsargs-propoptions-decorator